# Access href link value from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium

I currently have a dataframe I've produced through scraping https://www.cve.org/downloads.

```
 Format Unix Compressed (.Z)           Gzipped            Raw                                   Additional Notes
0    CSV       allitems.csv.Z   allitems.csv.gz   allitems.csv  NOTE: suitable for import into spreadsheet pro...
1   HTML      allitems.html.Z  allitems.html.gz  allitems.html                                                NaN
2   Text       allitems.txt.Z   allitems.txt.gz   allitems.txt                                                NaN
3    XML       allitems.xml.Z   allitems.xml.gz   allitems.xml                     XML Schema Design: cve_1.0.xsd
```

Under the Raw column, allitems.csv is actually a link in the website. Once I display it into a dataframe, the `href` value of the link could no longer be accessed. Below is the code I currently have using selenium and pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver


# from selenium import webdriver
Browser = webdriver.Safari()

# # To navigate to a URL:
Browser.get("http://cve.org/downloads")

# # To get raw html string:
RawHtmlString = Browser.page_source

df = pd.read_html(RawHtmlString)[0]

print(df)
```

How do I edit my program to be capable to extract the link and automatically download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Get links**

If you really want to *extract* the links, you could first get all the `a` tags nested inside `td` with attr `data-label="Raw"`, and then loop through them and get the `hrefs`. E.g.

```
raw = Browser.find_elements("xpath", "//td[@data-label='Raw']/a")

links = [r.get_attribute('href') for r in raw]

print(links)
['https://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/allitems.csv', 
 'https://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/allitems.html', 
 'https://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/allitems.txt', 
 'https://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/allitems.xml']
```

But if you're only interested in the `csv`, you could use:

```
csvs = Browser.find_elements(
    "xpath", "//td[@data-label='Raw']/a[contains(@href,'.csv')]")
links = [csv.get_attribute('href') for csv in csvs]

# or just use `find_element`, seeing that there is only one such file:

csv_link = Browser.find_element(
    "xpath", "//td[@data-label='Raw']/a[contains(@href,'.csv')]")\
    .get_attribute('href')
```

Of course, in this particular case, these would be quite pointless exercises. As you can see above, all links actually have the same base url. So, you can also simply create an extra column or something:

```
BASE = 'https://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/'
df['Urls'] = BASE + df.Raw

print(df.Urls)
0    https://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/allitems.csv
1    https://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/allitems....
2    https://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/allitems.txt
3    https://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/allitems.xml
Name: Urls, dtype: object
```

**Download files**

For downloading, I would rely on [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface). Note the warning, though, in the docs: "[This function] might become deprecated at some point in the future". *might*... That warning has been around for a while. Try something as follows:

```
from urllib import request

my_path = 'destination_folder_path/' # mind the "/" at the end!

for l in links:
    fname = l.rsplit('/', maxsplit=1)[1]
    print(l) # just to see what we're downloading
    request.urlretrieve(l, f'{my_path}{fname}')
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the above issue. However, for the downloading file portion. It does not seem to work. I've added replaced your placeholder in the ```my_path``` to ```'/Users/isaacagatep/desktop'``` but it does not auto download nor show the result of ```print(l)```. Am I missing something?

Comment: Odd, what do you get if you do `print(links)`. Is it empty? And which of the suggested options are you trying to use to fill the list `links` with the actual hrefs? Also, it should be `'/Users/isaacagatep/desktop/'` with the "/" at the end. Note, incidentally, that the files are really rather large. The download will take a while. Maybe, the code is just still processing.

Comment: I tried ```print(links)``` and it returned ```[]```. That means that it was empty in the first place. However, I've edited the code so that it is only retrieving the singular ```csv_link``` as you've shown. I'd only like to download that link.

Comment: Right, I'm not getting a warning on "By.XPATH" here, but that is probably a version issue. Updated the answer with "xpath" instead. If `csv_link` works with "xpath", then the other options should also work with that adjustment (if such need would occur). Please consider accepting the answer, if it solves your problem, so as to close the question.

Comment: yep, couldn't have worded it any better! Have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to access the `a href` part where the link is located, in order to get this text `"/data/downloads/file.csv.gz"`

```
s = requests.Session() 
link = '/data/downloads/file.csv.gz'
baseUrl= 'https://cve.mitre.org/'
```

Then you you apply something like this

```
s.get(url=urllib.parse.urljoin(baseurl,file_link),headers=headers)
```